# Explanation about cytogenetic notation

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, chromosome, cytogenetics

What is the correct meaning of cytogenetic notation "inv(4)(p13q22)" ?

1. Inversions at chromosome 4, at the p arm 13 is inverted AND at q
   arm 22 is inverted

OR

2. Inversions at chromosome 4, the p13 is
   Swapped with q22

Comment: Do you have a source

Answer (score 4):

Those are the break points of the inversion. So chromosome 4 was cut at p13 and q22 and the fragment was reinserted in the reverse direction, giving a pericentric inversion.

Comment: So the explanation number 1 is the correct !!!!

Comment: @d.putto Actually neither really sound correct to me.